# How can I upgrade ubuntu 20.04.6 when after apt-get update/get upgrade I get: Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, updates

I can't upgrade my current version of ubuntu 20.04.6, I would like to upgrade to the latest version
not sure if this is also a problem but when I list upgradable I get this message:

```
sudo apt list –upgradable
Listing... Error!
E: input:0-13: error: Expected pattern
   –upgradable
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I then proceed to these commands:

```
**sudo apt-get update**
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Get:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [3,569 B]      
Ign:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease      
Hit:8 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.1 InRelease
Ign:10 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 InRelease
Hit:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release
Err:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.1 Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 18.165.201.128 443]
Hit:13 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.1 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list:1
```

```
**sudo apt-get upgrade -y**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mongodb-mongosh
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
udo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mongodb-mongosh
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

```
**sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mongodb-mongosh
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

```
**sudo do-release-upgrade**
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

```
**sudo reboot.**
```

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

I have checked other replies from previous posts:

```
apt-mark showhold
mongodb-mongosh

sudo apt full-upgrade
the only thing that didn't update was that mongodb-mongosh
```

please help

Comment: there is no version 24.04.6 Please [edit] with the correct version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 3):

You have a third party repo (with hostname repo.mongodb.org) in your sources list.  This repo is failing to update its package index during `apt udpate` and subsequently failing to download updates to the package.

Third party repos are typically disabled during a dist upgrade anyway.  I would suggest you find that repo (in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`) and comment it out.   Then re-run apt-update and it should forget that mogodb still needs updates.

If you have important data in mongodb, you should dump it and back it up, because you may have to reload it from scratch after upgrading.

Then, after you upgrade, either use the mongodb that comes with Ubuntu or reinstall the repo from scratch (the URL may have changed) and take whatever action is necessary to restore the mongodb service.

Alternately, if you are not using mongodb, you could just remove the package entirely and do the update.  This might be cleaner, as if you leave it on the system without updating it, the system might retain dependencies from the previous OS version.  Sometimes this causes conflicts, sometimes it just leaves cruft behind that `apt autoremove` eventually will get.

Answer (score 2):

> sudo apt list –upgradable

You are supposed to use

```
apt list --upgradable
```

In the output of `sudo apt update`, you got

```
Err:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.1 Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 18.165.201.128 443]
```

This implies that the mongodb 6.1 repository you added, does not exist for Ubuntu 20.04.

Consider deleting the repository in Software and Sources.